# How to use i18n and next/image in next.config.js with TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, next.js, nextjs-image

I am trying to create a mini-application using TypeScript in NextJS since now [TypeScript](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/typescript) is supported in Next.js out of the box. And I also want to incorporate these two newly added features:

- [Image Component and Image Optimization (next/image)](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/image-optimization)
- [Internationalized Routing (i18n)](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing)

Take `i18n` for example:

```
// next.config.js
module.exports = {
    i18n: {
      // These are all the locales you want to support in
      // your application 
      // Sub-path Routing 
      locales: ['en', 'cn'],
      // This is the default locale you want to be used when visiting
      // a non-locale prefixed path e.g. `/hello`
      defaultLocale: 'en',
    },
  }
```

Unfortunately, I am having a really hard time using them in my `next.config.js`, as for the normal application (JavaScript only), it is working as it should. But for the TypeScript version, I am getting this error:

```
(node:15704) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot set property '__nextLocale' of undefined
```

It will be really helpful if any of you can help me out OR can give an example that how to properly use `next.config.js` and incorporate those new features in the TypeScript NextJS application.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no locale called 'en' neither 'cn'

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_localisation

I think that what you need:

```
const withImages = require('next-images')
const withPWA = require('next-pwa')

module.exports = withPWA(
withImages({
  images: {
    domains: [
    'images.ctfassets.net',
    'imgix.cosmicjs.com',
    'cdn.cosmicjs.com',
   ],
   i18n: {
      // These are all the locales you want to support in
      // your application
      locales: ['en-US', 'zh-CN'],
      // This is the default locale you want to be used when visiting
      // a non-locale prefixed path e.g. `/hello`
      defaultLocale: 'pt-BR',
      ...
   }
 },
```

Comment: The region is optional in [Next.js i18n](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing#getting-started) locales.